# Django request.data dictionary returns last item instead of list for post data from a form with checkboxes

Tags: django, forms, dictionary, checkbox

I have a form that contains checkboxes like so:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="">All<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="en">En<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="de">De<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="languages" value="ru">Ru<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Preview">
</form>
```

when send it, I can check and see all the data under request.data which looks like this:

```
MergeDict(<QueryDict: {u'languages': [u'', u'en', u'de']}>, <MultiValueDict: {}>)
```

I managed to get the selected language list using:

`dict(request.data.dicts[0].iterlists())['u'languages']`

But this seems ridiculous.

Trying a different way I get strange behavior. For example when i try to access `request.data['languages']` I get the last item from the list `u'de'`.

Can anyone explain this weird behavior? Why do I get this strange combination of MergeDict, QueryDict and MultiValueDict? And how should I best extract my list of checked values from it?

Comment: `request.POST.getlist('languages')`.

Comment: Thanks. `request.data.getlist('languages')` works as well and is preferred as we try to use this throughout. (more flexible than POST)

Answer (score 1):

Try to:

```
request.data.getlist('languages')
```

i have same problem,

```
<QueryDict: 
{
'hobbies': [
       'Gaming', 
       'Browsing', 
       'Coding' 
    ], 
'name': ['Elan'], 'email': ['elanian@gmail.com'], 'gender': ['W'], 'works': ['D']
}
>
```

i try in view :

```
print(form.data.getlist('hobbies'))
```

and show result

```
....
['Gaming', 'Browsing', 'Coding']
[19/Oct/2015 19:24:33] "POST /lecturer/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2158
```